# How to optimize matrix product of sparse and dense matrices in eigen when the result is selfadjoint

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am working with square matrices of type `std::complex<double>`. In particular, a sparse matrix `S` and a self-adjoint, dense matrix `H`, and I would like to compute the product of the form `S*H*S.adjoint()` and add it to another dense, self-adjoint matrix `J`. So a straight-forward way to do this in Eigen would be:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <complex>

Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> J, H;
Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double>> S;

// ...
// Set H, and J to be some self-adjoint matrices of the same size, and S also same
// size, but not necessarily self-adjoint.
// ...

J += S*H*S.adjoint();
```

But because `H` and `J` are self-adjoint and by the form of the product `S*H*S.adjoint()`, we know that `J` will remain self-adjoint after the operation. So there is really no need to compute the entire dense matrix result `S*H*S.adjoint()` and we could probably save some computation time by only computing the lower- or upper-triangular part of the result and adding that to the corresponding part of the matrix `J`. Eigen provides an API for this sort of optimization, but I'm not able to use it in this case. For example if instead of the sparse matrix `S` we had a dense matrix `D`, then doing

```
J += D*H*D.adjoint();
```

should be less efficient than

```
J.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>() = D*H*D.adjoint();
```

or

```
J.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>() = D*H.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>()*H.adjoint();
```

but the API doesn't seem to provide this level of optimization when computing the former product with a sparse matrix `S` instead of the dense matrix `D`. That is,

```
J.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>() = S*H*S.adjoint();
```

doesn't compile. So my question is: is there a way to tell Eigen to only compute the lower- (or upper-) triangular part of the matrix `S*H*S.adjoint()` and add it to the lower- (or upper-) triangular part of the self-adjoint matrix `J` to improve performance?

Perhaps even better would be an overload of a rank 1 update that looked something like

```
J.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>().rankUpdate(S,H);
```

Of course the current API doesn't support this form and to get the desired result would require taking the square root of `H`, call it `G` and do

```
J.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>().rankUpdate(S*G);
```

but although this should give the correct result, taking the square root is probably super expensive compared to the rest, so this would probably be slower.

The best performance I've found so far is

```
J.noalias() += S*H*S.adjoint();
```

Comment: How large are `S, H, J`? Do you know anything about `H` (how was it computed/generated)?

Comment: If you know the `v_k` vectors (and assuming there are not more than `N` of them), you can compute `SV=S*V` and then `J.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>() = SV * P.asDiagonal() * SV.adjoint()`.

Comment: For my application, `S, H, J` would be size NxN with anything from a few (e.g. N = 3) up to N = 1000 or more, but the performance wouldn't matter as much below N = 50 so the case I'm interested in optimizing the performance for is typically something like 50 < N < 1000. Yes `H` has some additional properties: it can be any matrix that satisfies H = sum_k p_k v_k v_k^*, where p_k are real, and p_k <= 1, and sum_k p_k = 1, v_k are normalized eigenvectors of H, so v_k has shape Nx1, and v_k^* v_k = 1, and v_k^* is the adjoint of v_k (so v_k^* has shape 1xN).

Comment: Yeah that might be a good way if I know `v_k`, but in general I don't know them, and finding them essentially requires diagonalising `H` which is expensive.

Comment: My question was aiming for practical properties of `H`. Every self-adjoint matrix can be diagonalised (with real eigenvalues), so the only additional property you describe is that `trace H = 1`, which I'm afraid won't help that much.

Comment: Yes true. So yeah in my case `H` could be any self-adjoint matrix with trace 1.